# Why is render :json in view.json.erb result in error, wants :partial, :template, :inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In controller:

```
def some_action
  @foo = 'bar'
end
```

and in `some_action.json.erb`:

```
<%= render :json => @foo %>
```

This results in error:

```
ArgumentError - You invoked render but did not give any of :partial, :template, :inline, :file or :text option.:
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:36:in `ActionView::TemplateRenderer#determine_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `ActionView::TemplateRenderer#render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `ActionView::Renderer#render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `ActionView::Renderer#render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.10/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `#<Class:0xb4a2378>#render'
   ...
```

As much as I wrap my head around it, I can't see why `render :json => ...` shouldn't work here. I know I can render directly from controller for format.json, I'm trying to do it through a view though, and without manually crafting the json in the .erb.

Rails 3.2.10 on Ruby 1.9

Comment: `render :json` is meant to be used in a controller. Try to simply do `@foo.to_json`. But you'd rather use a json builder

Comment: Try to add the param :partial => "some_action" to the render helper

Comment: Is this related to the difference between rendering before the response headers were set (ContentType etc) and after? Seems that `render :json` wants full control of response (header + content) but rendering inside a view is already too late for setting headers so only certain types of `render`s are supported.

Comment: @Resmus Rusanu: no, the headers are not sent before the views get evaluated. It's just that the `render` method in a view context and the `render` method in the controller context are two different methods, and the former doesn't expect the `:json` option. See: [ActionController::Rendering](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionController/Rendering) & [ActionView::Helpers::RenderingHelper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper/render)

Comment: @Leventix: D'oh, that clarifies it... can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`render` method in a view context](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render) and the [`render` method in the controller context](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render) are two different methods, and the former doesn't expect the `:json` option.

As [apneadiving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving) suggested, use `@foo.to_json` or a json builder.